# How to convert a Path into a const char* for FFI?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to take a [`PathBuf`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) which represents a file location,
and pass it into a C library to save an image to that location.

I can see that I can turn the `PathBuf` into an [`OsString`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html), and using [`std::os::unix::ffi`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/index.html), I can turn it into `Vec<u8>`, and from there, a [`CString`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html), but this seems somewhat convoluted and platform specific.

Is that really the best we can do at this point?  I'd rather not limit this to Unix only over an issue as small as this, since everything else works on Windows as far as I know.

Comment: For extra background, I'm trying to wrap cairo idiomatically, though I'm really just looking for a generic answer (hence why this is not part of the question).

Comment: The problem on Windows is that interacting with Unicode paths requires going through a different API. `char *` is only for code pages . Maybe you can at least work with ASCII paths, but generally on Windows a `OsString` is not a `char *`. This is partially the problem of the maintainer of the C library you're using.

Comment: Specifically, on *nix-like platforms, [OsStr is Vec<u8>](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a1e3c25a2688664e85052b6205187b62410c0df0/src/libstd/sys/unix/os_str.rs#L24-L26), but on Windows it [is a Wtf8Buf](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a1e3c25a2688664e85052b6205187b62410c0df0/src/libstd/sys/windows/os_str.rs#L23-L25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to wrap something like `cairo_surface_write_to_png`, you're probably better off just re-implementing it yourself in terms of `cairo_surface_write_to_png_stream`, using Rust for the file IO.

---

The problem is more or less that paths on Windows are UTF-16, and there is (as far as I know), no 8-bit encoding (*i.e.* representable as `const char *`) that Windows will accept which can correctly store all possible paths.  In effect, if you're using `const char *` for paths on Windows, you're Doing It Wrong™.

Rust works around this by using *neither* UTF-16 or UTF-8 on Windows; instead, it uses [WTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) which is a non-standard extension to UTF-8 to encode the full UTF-16 space.  But, this also means that the actual, internal representation of a Rust path on Windows is effectively useless outside of Rust itself.

Comment: Ah, I see, so I could use something like this example: http://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2007-May/010677.html
but just performing the write call myself, to a file I open using the path.